# inner join in sql returning same exposed names error

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am trying to do an assignment for college but i cant wrap my head around inner join, i have tried googling tutorials but nothing is sticking for me. What i basically have to do is display the names, salarys and department names of all the employees in the US.

I know i have to display departments.department_name, employees.First/Last_name, employees.salary.
but i dont know how to write it

```
e.department_id = d.department_id
d.location_id = l.location_id
l.country_id = c.country.id
where c.country.id = 'united states of america'
```

and

somehow find the department name and output that as well.

Here are my tables http://puu.sh/bIxzX/591c708f27.png

Comment: Well, I can't offer an answer as I would be doing your homework for you. So allow me to break it up a bit: You want to use an inner join to find the Employees and Locations (their intersection), then you'll need an outer join to link up Department to the result to be able to convey the department name. Try thinking of it in two steps, like that. Get the first piece running, then add the second piece.

Comment: @GreyDog Alright, ill report back with results. And thanks for not just answering, i want to learn how to do it for the future.

Comment: Good luck. Stare at this for an hour. It's database gold. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Comment: @GreyDog I get stuck here every time, i dont know what the problem is http://puu.sh/bIzLg/1b98f48ba0.png

Comment: @GreyDog: Who says school kids don't need to know VENN diagrams anymore.

Comment: @GreyDog further down the rabit hole i go http://puu.sh/bIA70/9c94ca9e2d.png

Comment: @GreyDog I think i figured it out http://puu.sh/bIAmW/12e4331e11.png

Comment: @greydog last one but this is actually what i was looking for: http://puu.sh/bIAvL/8f825cb87a.png thanks for all your help.

Comment: You've got the INNER JOIN syntax mixed up. If you have a list of tables that you need to join they should each be separated by a single JOIN statement. You have two commma seperated tables at the top - why is that?

Comment: Lookin' good!! You'll be stealing my job, soon.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid To be honest i have no idea what i did, but it worked so im happy.

Comment: OK, I'll explain: your `from` clause should not have this code in it at all: `Locations as a, Departments as b,`, and you should also not be using `DISTINCT`. Good on you for trying to learn this stuff properly. I can explain further if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comments, you found a solution for your problem but your query is mixing some old school syntax (highly recommended to NOT use it) with explicit jointures and you almost used aliases but missed it.

Here is the same query without useless code and you'll find some explanation below:

```
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME
    ,E.LAST_NAME
    ,E.SALARY
    ,D.DEPARTMENT_NAME
    ,L.Street_Address
FROM Employees E
INNER JOIN Departments D ON D.DEPARTMENT_ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID
INNER JOIN Locations L ON L.Location_id = D.LOCATION_ID
INNER JOIN Countries C ON C.Country_ID = L.Country_ID
                         AND C.Country_Name = 'united states of america'
```

In this query, i use aliases in order to simplify the readability. The table `Employees` has alias `E`, the table `Departments` has alias `D`,...

If you have explicit jointures (`... JOIN TableName ON ...`), you don't need to declare these tables in your `FROM` clause (this comma-separated notation is obsolete and you need to avoid it).

The last detail about my query is that i moved your `WHERE` condition directly in the jointure condition with the table `Countries`. This is not required but by doing so, the condition is applied during the jointure with this table instead of being applied on the entire result of the query (in this situation the performance will probably not be noticeable, but keep that in mind).

Hope this will help you to better understand what you've done.